# HTML CSS flexbox в Chrome и Firefox по разному отображается

Tags: css, html5, вёрстка, flexbox, кроссбраузерность

Это в Chrome:

[image: Так отображается в хроме]

Это в Firefox:

[image: В мозилле все красиво -конфетка]

Волнует обратный звонок - кнопка и почта  - с конвертиком `editpress@info`.
Нет более сил бороться, сроки поджимают - убил уже более 6 часов - одинаково не могу добиться. Получается одинаково если дополнительно прописать в `<div class="r1">` с зеленой кнопкой обратного вызова `style="align-self:strange;"`, но тогда кнопка везде одинаково(и в Chrome и в Firefox), но правда длиннее чем верхний телефон, что некрасиво.

Вёрстка:

```css
.grid_row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}



.grid_item {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 15px;
}
/********************************************************/
.header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    padding: 25px 25px 0px 15px;
    height:205px;
   
}

.header_item1 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 7;
    height: 205px;
}

.header_item2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 3;
    height: 205px;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------*/

/***************start block logo************************/
.logoBlok, .head_tel1 {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content:space-around;
    height: 120px;
    align-items:flex-start;
    /*padding: 20px 25px 10px 10px;*/
}

.logo img {
    display: flex;
    max-width: 100%;
    /*min-width:1;*/
}

.r1 {
    /*align-items: stretch;*/
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border: solid 1px orange;
}

    .r1 p {
        color: #828282;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 6px 0px 0px 0px;
        font-weight: 600;
    }

.r1_item1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #33B086;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.r1_item2 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #828282;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-wrap: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


/*------------------end block logo------------------------------------------*/

/**********start tel1***********/

.backCall {
    padding: 0% 13% 0% 15%;
    height: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ECECEC;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-size: 18px;
    background: url(../Images/trubka.png) no-repeat 5% 50%,#33B086;
    border:solid 1px red;
   /*width:100%;*/
   
}

.backEmail {
    padding: 0% 13% 0% 15%;
    height: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #828282;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-align: center;
    background: url(../Images/konvert.png) no-repeat 0% 50%;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
            <div class="header_item1">
                <div class="grid_row" style="height:120px;">
                    <div class="logoBlok">
                        <div class="logo">
                            <a href="/home/index"><img src="~/Images/Logo2.png" /></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="r1">
                            <h1 class="r1_item1">
                                СУВЕНИРЫ ОПТОМ
                            </h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="r1">
                            <h1 class="r1_item2">
                                С ВАШИМ ЛОГОТИПОМ
                            </h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="head_tel1">
                        <div class="r1"><h1 class="tel">8 (800) 333-50-90</h1></div>
                        <div class="r1"><p>бесплатный звонок по России</p></div>
                        <div class="r1"><a href="#" class="backCall">обратный звонок</a></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="head_tel1">
                        <div class="r1"><h1 class="tel">8 (499) 705-55-50</h1></div>
                        <div class="r1"><p>Пн - Пт с 10 до 19 часов</p></div>
                        <div class="r1">
                            <a href="mailto:info@EditPressRu" class="backEmail">info@EditPress.Ru</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="grid_row" style="height:75px; padding-right:30px;">
                    <form style="display:flex;height:100%;width:100%;" action="/products/SearchProducts" method="post">
                        <div class="search">
                            <div class="poisk">
                                <input id="queryString" name="queryString" style="width:100%;border:none;background: #ECECEC;" placeholder="поиск" type="text" />
                                <input id="SearchSubmit" type="submit" value="" style="background:url(/images/lupa.png) no-repeat center center;width:35px;border:none;cursor:pointer;" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="razdely">
                               
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <div class="header_item2">
                <div class="cart">
                    <div class="cart-item" style="display:flex;flex-direction:column;justify-content:center;">
                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    <p id="sum_tovar" style="color:#33B086;font-size:25px;padding-right:65px;background:url(/images/cart.png) no-repeat 80% 30%;background-size:contain;">
                      
                    </p>
                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cart-item" style="border-left:solid 1px #919191;padding:2px 0px 2px 20px;">
                        <p style="color:#EA2C3E;">15 000 P</p>
                        <p style="color:#828282;">минимальная</p>
                        <p style="color:#828282;">сумма заказа</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="socSet">
                    <div class="socItem face">

                    </div>
                    <div class="socItem vkont">

                    </div>
                    <div class="socItem twit">

                    </div>
                    <div class="socItem inst">

                    </div>
                    <div class="socItem telegr">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: а вы не пробовали добавить префиксы?

Comment: css пока что сырой, поправлю и сокращу,но суть заложена.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.grid_row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}



.grid_item {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 15px;
}
/********************************************************/
.header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    padding: 25px 25px 0px 15px;
    height:205px;
   
}

.header_item1 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 7;
    height: 205px;
}

.header_item2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 3;
    height: 205px;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------*/

/***************start block logo************************/
.logoBlok, .head_tel1 {        
    flex: 1 0 auto;/*ПРАВКА*/
    display: block;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content:space-around;
    height: 120px;
    align-items:flex-start;
    /*padding: 20px 25px 10px 10px;*/
}

.logo img {
    display: flex;
    max-width: 100%;
    /*min-width:1;*/
}

.r1 {
    /*align-items: stretch;*/
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border: solid 1px orange;
}

    .r1 p {
        color: #828282;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 6px 0px 0px 0px;
        font-weight: 600;
    }

.r1_item1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #33B086;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.r1_item2 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #828282;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-wrap: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


/*------------------end block logo------------------------------------------*/

/**********start tel1***********/

.backCall {
    padding: 0% 13% 0% 15%;
    height: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ECECEC;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-size: 18px;
    background: url(../Images/trubka.png) no-repeat 5% 50%,#33B086;
    border:solid 1px red;
   /*width:100%;*/
   
}

.backEmail {
    padding: 0% 13% 0% 15%;
    height: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #828282;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-align: center;
    background: url(../Images/konvert.png) no-repeat 0% 50%;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
            <div class="header_item1">
                <div class="grid_row" style="height:120px;">
                    <div class="logoBlok">
                        <div class="logo">
                            <a href="/home/index"><img src="~/Images/Logo2.png" /></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="r1">
                            <h1 class="r1_item1">
                                СУВЕНИРЫ ОПТОМ
                            </h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="r1">
                            <h1 class="r1_item2">
                                С ВАШИМ ЛОГОТИПОМ
                            </h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="head_tel1">
                        <div class="r1"><h1 class="tel">8 (800) 333-50-90</h1></div>
                        <div class="r1"><p>бесплатный звонок по России</p></div>
                        <div class="r1"><a href="#" class="backCall">обратный звонок</a></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="head_tel1">
                        <div class="r1"><h1 class="tel">8 (499) 705-55-50</h1></div>
                        <div class="r1"><p>Пн - Пт с 10 до 19 часов</p></div>
                        <div class="r1">
                            <a href="mailto:info@EditPressRu" class="backEmail">info@EditPress.Ru</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="grid_row" style="height:75px; padding-right:30px;">
                    <form style="display:flex;height:100%;width:100%;" action="/products/SearchProducts" method="post">
                        <div class="search">
                            <div class="poisk">
                                <input id="queryString" name="queryString" style="width:100%;border:none;background: #ECECEC;" placeholder="поиск" type="text" />
                                <input id="SearchSubmit" type="submit" value="" style="background:url(/images/lupa.png) no-repeat center center;width:35px;border:none;cursor:pointer;" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="razdely">
                               
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <div class="header_item2">
                <div class="cart">
                    <div class="cart-item" style="display:flex;flex-direction:column;justify-content:center;">
                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    <p id="sum_tovar" style="color:#33B086;font-size:25px;padding-right:65px;background:url(/images/cart.png) no-repeat 80% 30%;background-size:contain;">
                      
                    </p>
                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cart-item" style="border-left:solid 1px #919191;padding:2px 0px 2px 20px;">
                        <p style="color:#EA2C3E;">15 000 P</p>
                        <p style="color:#828282;">минимальная</p>
                        <p style="color:#828282;">сумма заказа</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="socSet">
                    <div class="socItem face">

                    </div>
                    <div class="socItem vkont">

                    </div>
                    <div class="socItem twit">

                    </div>
                    <div class="socItem inst">

                    </div>
                    <div class="socItem telegr">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Вы гений, спасибище!!!!!! Золотая голова!